# How to left aligned subfigure

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats, figure-placement

[image: Screenshot]

I want to aligne the subfigure C with the subfigure A as shown on screenshot.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Example-image-a}
\caption{Subfig 1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{Example-image-b}
\caption{Subfig 2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.30]{Example-image-c}
\caption{Subfig 3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Fig}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Note that `Example-image-a.pdf` (or any other extension) is not a distributed file. Case insensitive systems such as Windows *may* find `example-image-a.pdf`, but not using the real name can lead to portability problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `scale`, because with it you have no control on the final size.

In the code below I reserve half of the text width for each subfigure; the images are 75% of the reserved width.

The trick is to have an empty line to separate the two rows (I also added `\medskip` in between).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Subfig 1}
\end{subfigure}% <--- don't forget
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Subfig 2}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip

\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Subfig 3}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Fig}
\label{fig}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change your mind and decide that the third image should be centered, just add `\centering` after `\begin{figure}`

[image]

Comment: And if I want to align the subfigure C with the subfigure B, is the code widely different?

Comment: @hofmannj Just replace `\centering` with, or add, `\raggedleft`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer to hofmannj's comment question, consider this correctio to egreg's answer:

```
\hfill  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{Subfig 3}
        \end{subfigure}
```

Output:

[image]